# CDO.Message delivery notification failed

Tags: email, vb6, ms-access-2003, cdo.message

Here is my environment: Windows Server 2003, Microsoft Access 2003, Microsoft VB 6.5
Trying to send email from Access using CDO.Message. Here is the portion of my code:

```
Private Sub btnTestEmail_Click()

On Error GoTo SendMail_Error:

Dim Mailmsg As Object
Dim mailconf As Object
Dim McFields As Object
Dim strSchemas As String

Set Mailmsg = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
Set mailconf = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")
Set McFields = mailconf.Fields

strSchemas = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/"
With McFields
    .Item(strSchemas & "sendusing") = 2
    .Item(strSchemas & "smtpserver") = "smtp.gmail.com"
    .Item(strSchemas & "smtpserverport") = 465
    .Item(strSchemas & "smtpauthenticate") = 1
    .Item(strSchemas & "sendusername") = "my_email@gmail.com"
    .Item(strSchemas & "sendpassword") = "my_gmail_password"
    .Item(strSchemas & "smtpconnectiontimeout") = 60
    .Item(strSchemas & "smtpusessl") = 1
    .Update
End With

Set Mailmsg.Configuration = mailconf

With Mailmsg
    .TextBody = "Test email body text"
    .Subject = "Test email subject"
    .To = "target_email@gmail.com"
    .from = "my_email@gmail.com"
    '.AddAttachment "D:\test.pdf"

    .Fields("urn:schemas:mailheader:disposition-notification-to") = "my_email@gmail.com"
    .Fields("urn:schemas:mailheader:return-receipt-to") = "my_email@gmail.com"

    ' Set delivery status notification (DSN)
    '  Name                      Value   Description
    '  cdoDSNDefault             0       No DSN commands are issued.
    '  cdoDSNNever               1       No DSN commands are issued.
    '  cdoDSNFailure             2       Return a DSN if delivery fails.
    '  cdoDSNSuccess             4       Return a DSN if delivery succeeds.
    '  cdoDSNDelay               8       Return a DSN if delivery is delayed.
    '  cdoDSNSuccessFailOrDelay  14      Return a DSN if delivery succeeds, fails, or is

    .DSNOptions = 0

    .Fields.Update
    .Send
End With

MsgBox "Message Sent", vbOKOnly

Set Mailmsg = Nothing
Set mailconf = Nothing
Set McFields = Nothing

Exit Sub

SendMail_Error:
MsgBox Err.Description, vbOKOnly

End Sub
```

With DSNOptions = 0 works great but I would like to get delivery notification (not read notification).
If I set DSNOptions to any allowed non-zero value the email doesn't even arrives to the target email and I don't get any notification to my email.
Strange thing if I set unexisting target email (on purpose) I get delivery unsuccessful notification even with DSNOptions = 0.
Am I missing something in the code? Found on multiple other web site people claims this code works but using other smtp servers. Any help appreciated.